# Powershell Script to Start Service if it is Stopped and wait for minute and send an email notification

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am very new to Powershell and in learning stage, I have tried to create an script to do automate below task. This script is not working as i am expected. Could you please review it and give me some help on it.

My task is,

I am trying to find out SQL Services (more than one SQL services in multiple servers) which are in stopped state and trying to start it, Waiting for an minute to complete the service start and verifying the service status again. If still it is stopped state i am trying to sending an email to setup of people for an action.

Could you please review the below code and correct the mistake, i tried to find it but unable to do

```
#Define servers & Services Variables
$Servers = GC "E:\Bhanu\SQLServer.txt"
$Services = GC "E:\Bhanu\SQLService.txt"

#Function Call
Function ServiceStatus ($Servers, $Services)
{
    foreach ($Server in $Servers)
    {
        foreach ($Service in $Services)
        {
            $Servicestatus = get-service -ComputerName $Server -Name $Service
            if ($Servicestatus.Status -eq "Stopped")
            {
                Start-service $Service          
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 60            
                $ServiceStatus1 = Get-Service -ComputerName $Server -Name $Service
                if ($Servicestatus1.Status -eq "Stopped")
                {            
                FuncMail -To “abc@gmail.com” -From “abc@gmail.com” -Subject $Server + $Service "fails to Start, Take immediate Action to avoid Impact” -Body $ServiceName "Service fails to Start, Take immediate Action to avoid Impact” -smtpServer “servername”
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


function FuncMail 
{
    #param($strTo, $strFrom, $strSubject, $strBody, $smtpServer)
    param($To, $From, $Subject, $Body, $smtpServer)
    $msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
    $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
    $msg.From = $From
    $msg.To.Add($To)
    $msg.Subject = $Subject
    $msg.IsBodyHtml = 1
    $msg.Body = $Body
    $smtp.Send($msg)
}
```

servicestatus $Servers $Services

Please let me know if you need anything here from my end

Comment: you have defined serviceStatus function but  never made a call to it

Comment: You haven't told us in what way it's not behaving as you expect?

Comment: Need more information on if there is an error occurring here or not. Also, there is no need for your FuncMail function when there is a `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet that is already available.

Comment: This does not affect your code but I it looks like you have extra braces around `Start-Sleep` that do not need to be there. I was trying to clean up the extra spacing which is when I noticed them.

Comment: Yes, we definitely need to know what it is actually doing...  Also, You should move everyrthing from the Start-Sleep cmdlet to the e-mail function into the same scope as If statement for Start-server, otherwise you're adding extra wait time and processing for no reason

Comment: Without knowing exactly what the problem is, I would hazard a guess that it's a permission issue.  The account that's being used to run this script must be part of the local Administrators group on the target server in order to interact with its services.

Comment: @Taegost, Thanks for your reply, I am running with this script with my credentials. I have admin access to remote server.

Comment: @Matt, I have tried to remove the braces aroung start-sleep...but no luck...When i am trying to execute it's showing completed in Powershell ISE without any error. But actually it is not sending any email OR not starting the service. I dont know what error it is throwing because actually not showing any error instead showing COMPLETED

Comment: @Nanhydrin: When i am trying to execute it's showing completed in Powershell ISE without any error. But actually it is not sending any email OR not starting the service. I dont know what error it is throwing because actually not showing any error instead showing COMPLETED

Comment: @Taegost, As per your sugesstions i have moved everything from the start-sleep to e-mail function but no luck. Actually it is running and showing completed without any error but service not started & no email recevied.

Comment: is this the whole script? I mean I don't see anything at the end actually initiating the call to the primary `ServiceStatus` function so nothing is actually executing? Very last line I would presume needs to simply be `ServiceStatus`?

Comment: @bhanuprakash - Can you update your script now that you've made the changes so we can all see it?  Also: 1) Having admin access and being part of the Administrators group aren't always the same thing, depending on how the security is set up.  2) Have you tried taking the code that starts the service out to run by itself so you can ensure it works the way you expect?  Last) Have you verified that the values you're pulling out of the text files is exactly what you expect it to be?  I'd go so far as to start off the loop with a .Trim() on both the $Server and $Service variables

Comment: @ Taegost, I am very new to powershell, so i am not sure whether i have done correct or not. My apologize if it is wrong. I have updated the script in Question since limitation in Comment section. Please review it and correct the mistake

Comment: @ssaviers, Thanks for your find...Yes i missed it, No wonder why it is not doing any thing...Now i have updated the script and getting below error. Start-Service : Cannot find any service with service name 'BMR Boot Service'.
At line:14 char:26
+             Start-service <<<<  $Service}
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (BMR Boot Service:String) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand....I think it is looking in local system from where i am executing instead of remote system

Comment: @bhanuprakash - You made the update I suggested perfectly (I would have reused the $Servicestatus variable, but it shouldn't be an issue).  As for your new error, it's good that we're making progress.  What's the value of the $Server variable when it makes the call that's generating the error?

Comment: are you sure you are using the actual service name in your text file vs the service description? for example "Windows Update" is the description but the name of the service is "wuauserv". The spaces in your name reference is what leads me to suspect this is the case. If so change the text file to use the actual service name otherwise you will need to add more code to look for description based selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi this isn't the best approach and i'm doing it in quick way.
note %=foreach-object; ?=Where-Object.

You have to save your password on one file if your smtp-server require authentication otherwise don't run it using `read-host -assecurestring | convertfrom-securestring | out-file "C:\Secure\Password.txt"`

I'm also assuming you have your servers saved on one file.
My solution is to start all sql server service if you want to start specific just save the service name on one file on separate line.

The code to execute bellow.

```
#Loading Server and service details
$Services=Get-content C:\PS\Service.txt
$servidores=get-content C:\PS\Servers\Servers.txt

#Loading Mail credential
$Mailpasswordpath="C:\PS\Securestring.txt"
$Mailusername="DOmain\User"
$password=cat $Mailpasswordpath |ConvertTo-Securestring
$Cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Mailusername,$password


$servidores|Foreach-Object{Get-Service -ComputerName $_ -Name $Services }|  #Get the services running on all servers
Where-Object{$_.Status -eq "Stopped"}| #Which status is equal stopped
Foreach-Object{
     $_.Start(); #try to start
     Start-Sleep -Seconds 60;  #wait one minute
     $_.Refresh();  #refresh then service to update status

     #validate is status still stopped
     if($_.Status -eq "Stopped") 
     {
         #LOADING Mail details
         $To="user@domain.com"
         $subject="$($_.MachineName) $($_.Name)  fails to Start, Take immediate Action to avoid Impact"
         $From="ServiceStatus@domain.com"
         $smtp="Server.domain.com"
         $body="$($_.Name) Service fails to Start, Take immediate Action to avoid Impact"

         #Sending email to notify
         Send-MailMessage -To $To -Subject $subject  -From $From  -SmtpServer $smtp  -Body $body  -Credential $Cred
     }
}
```

**P.S: It's not the best approach I only decide to solve this problem. if you want we can create a function together later just test it first.**

Comment: I would definitely recommend when giving examples to someone who is new to Powershell that you don't use abbreviations or include a bunch of commands on one line

Comment: I Agree with you @Taegost. that's why i gave a brief explanation of abbreviation on top of my answer. I will correct according to your suggestion.

ONCE AGAIN SORRY TO ALL OF YOU GUYS WHO WOULD LIKE TO TRY THIS APPROACH. I THINK SOME GHOST START TYPING MY CODE. :)

Comment: @Taegost I hope now it's half improved than before, thanks for your tips
I hope this solution became readble and user friendly

Comment: Hi Felicio, Thanks for your help, i hope it will work, i will test it again let you know.

Comment: I have one question here, I am actually trying to monitor set of SQL Services for multiple servers remotely. I am giving MSSQL*, SQL* as service name in SQLService.txt file in one line each will it work ? I tried this approach in my code initially but it didn't work. Pls suggest

Comment: @Taegost, Thanks a lot for your inputs

Comment: Why are you giving two service name with pratically sam pattern you can't use `*SQL*` instead?. I tested with two service. on file and it worked. But as @Taegost said you must guarantee that you are administrator in all servers. I run this script in two computers remotely and it worked. To send email using personalization you must guarantee that your mail server accept it and that your account have permission to  use it otherwise use you mail credential with your mail account

Comment: Felicio, You are awesome. Yes (<star>SQL<star>) (start symbol is not taking, dont know how to do that) is working, It is checking all SQL services. Thanks a lot. Will check in our actual servers and let you know the status. Thanks to all who helped me on this.

Comment: You welcome @bhanuprakash.  i'm not that awesome. i will be waiting for your feedback.

Comment: @ Felicio, Thanks for your help. I am very sorry for late reply, It was tested in autual servers and working as we expected. Thanks once again to all who helped me on this.